# Regex that matches punctuation at the word boundary including underscore

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a Python regex for a variable phrase with the following properties:
(For the sake of example, let's assume the variable phrase here is taking the value `and`. But note that I need to do this in a way that the thing playing the role of `and` can be passed in as a variable which I'll call `phrase`.)

Should match: `this_and`, `this.and`, `(and)`, `[and]`, `and^`, `;And`, etc.

Should not match: `land`, `andy`

This is what I tried so far (where `phrase` is playing the role of `and`):

```
pattern = r"\b  " + re.escape(phrase.lower()) + r"\b"
```

This seems to work for all my requirements except that it does not match words with underscores e.g. `\_hello`, `hello\_`, `hello_world`.

Edit: Ideally I would like to use the standard library re module rather than any external packages.

Comment: I think you need a custom word boundary with a negative lookbehind, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56308893/3832970).

Comment: Did you have time to check the answers? Please consider accepting one that worked best for you.

Answer (score 4):

You may use

```
r'(?<![^\W_])and(?![^\W_])'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpmF92/1). Compile with the `re.I` flag to enable case insensitive matching.

**Details**

- `(?<![^\W_])` - the preceding char should not be a letter or digit char
- `and` - some keyword
- `(?![^\W_])` - the next char cannot be a letter or digit

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/x7wINw):

```
import re
strs = ['this_and', 'this.and', '(and)', '[and]', 'and^', ';And', 'land', 'andy']
phrase = "and"
rx = re.compile(r'(?<![^\W_]){}(?![^\W_])'.format(re.escape(phrase)), re.I)
for s in strs:
    print("{}: {}".format(s, bool(rx.search(s))))
```

Output:

```
this_and: True
this.and: True
(and): True
[and]: True
and^: True
;And: True
land: False
andy: False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex that might solve it:

**Regex**

```
(?<=[\W_]+|^)and(?=[\W_]+|$)
```

**Example**

```
# import regex

string = 'this_And'
test = regex.search(r'(?<=[\W_]+|^)and(?=[\W_]+|$)', string.lower())
print(test.group(0))
# prints 'and'

# No match
string = 'Andy'
test = regex.search(r'(?<=[\W_]+|^)and(?=[\W_]+|$)', string.lower())
print(test)
# prints None

strings = [ "this_and", "this.and", "(and)", "[and]", "and^", ";And"]
[regex.search(r'(?<=[\W_]+|^)and(?=[\W_]+|$)', s.lower()).group(0) for s in strings if regex.search(r'(?<=[\W_]+|^)and(?=[\W_]+|$)', s.lower())]
# prints ['and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and']
```

**Explanation**

`[\W_]+` means we accept before (`?<=`) or after (`?=`) `and` only non-word symbols except the underscore `_` (a word symbol that) is accepted. `|^` and `|$` allow matches to lie at the edge of the string.

**Edit**

As mentioned in my comment, the module `regex` does not yield errors with variable lookbehind lengths (as opposed to `re`).

```
# This works fine
# import regex
word = 'and'
pattern = r'(?<=[\W_]+|^){}(?=[\W_]+|$)'.format(word.lower())
string = 'this_And'
regex.search(pattern, string.lower())
```

However, if you insist on using `re`, then of the top of my head I'd suggest splitting the lookbehind in two `(?<=[\W_])and(?=[\W_]+|$)|^and(?=[\W_]+|$)` that way cases where the string starts with `and` are captured as well.

```
# This also works fine
# import re
word = 'and'
pattern = r'(?<=[\W_]){}(?=[\W_]+|$)|^{}(?=[\W_]+|$)'.format(word.lower(), word.lower())
string = 'this_And'
re.search(pattern, string.lower())
```

Comment: Thank you. I need the thing playing the role of `and` to be a variable which I'll call `phrase` (updated the question to reflect that). Based on what you said, I tried 

```
pattern = r"(?<=[\W_]+|^)" + re.escape(phrase.lower()) + r"(?=[\W]+|$)"

```
But I got the following error message:

```
error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
``` 
Can you advise on how to get around this?

Comment: @AlexBoche I see. I haven't tried it myself yet, but I suspect this error actually comes from using the module `re`. Try using the module `regex`, it might work then.